Wildcards and basis
I have a doubt which I probably should know the answer to. I'm confused though. This question regards UST bond future basis. I won't explain the abbreviations as they should be clear to someone who can answer.
Basis net of carry (BNOC) in a basis sense has the switch/end of month optionality value in it. But say the wild card of delivering another bond is more profitable (say just due to conversion factor differences). Would that reflect in BNOC, and therefore make this the cheapest to deliver? I can see arguments both ways.
Was hoping someone can elucidate.
